# Initializing a List with arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I want to populate a List of string arrays at compile time

something like this:

```
        List<string[]> synonyms = new List<string[]> 
        {
            { "enabled", "enable", "enabling" },
            { "disabled", "disable", "disabling" },
            { "s0", "s0 state" },
            { "s5", "s5 state" }
        };
```

but I get a compile error:
`No overloaded method 'Add' takes 2 arguments`

Why is this? It works if they weren't string arrays with `List<string>`

Comment: You are treating your collection as a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: Dictionaries can only contain a pair, I want to be able to contain more than a pair if necessary

Comment: In that case you might need some custom model class that takes your left value, eg. s0 or s5, and in that custom model add synonyms that are a list of strings. What you have at the moment is not going to work.

Comment: I don't want the left value to be treated differently than the other synonyms. Basically we have a huge codebase and I need to make "enabled" == "enable"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that your code does *not* work is spelled out in [How to: Initialize a Dictionary with a Collection Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx):

> A Dictionary contains a collection of key/value pairs. Its Add method takes two parameters, one for the key and one for the value. To initialize a Dictionary, **or any collection whose Add method takes multiple parameters**, enclose each set of parameters in braces...

Thus, in the syntax

```
    {
        { "enabled", "enable", "enabling" },
    }
```

The compiler is expecting your collection to have an `Add(string, string, string)` method.  Because there is no such method on `List<string []>`, your compilation fails.

In fact, it's possible to make such a collection and initialize it with this syntax.  If you create the following collection:

```
public class TripleCollection<T> : IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T, T>>
{
    readonly List<Tuple<T, T, T>> list = new List<Tuple<T, T, T>>();

    public void Add(T first, T second, T third)
    {
        list.Add(Tuple.Create(first, second, third));
    }

    public IEnumerator<Tuple<T, T, T>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The following will compile successfully and create a collection with one 3-tuple:

```
        var tuples = new TripleCollection<string>
        {
            { "1", "2", "3" },
        };
```

You can also make the following `List` subclass:

```
public class ListOfArray<T> : List<T[]>
{
    public new void Add(params T[] args)
    {
        base.Add(args);
    }
}
```

And initialize it with the desired syntax:

```
        var synonyms = new ListOfArray<string>
        {
            { "enabled", "enable", "enabling" },
            { "disabled", "disable", "disabling" },
            { "s0", "s0 state" },
            { "s5", "s5 state" }
        };
```

But for `List<string []>`, as others have noted, you need to initialize your synonyms list by explicitly allocating each `string []` entry, rather than using an implicit collection intializer for each entry:

```
        var synonyms = new List<string[]>
        {
            new [] { "enabled", "enable", "enabling" },
            new [] { "disabled", "disable", "disabling" },
            new [] { "s0", "s0 state" },
            new [] { "s5", "s5 state" }
        };
```

Answer (score 8):

You aren't creating arrays in your example, try the following:

```
    List<string[]> synonyms = new List<string[]> 
    {
        new[] { "enabled", "enable", "enabling" },
        new[] { "disabled", "disable", "disabling" },
        new[] { "s0", "s0 state" },
        new[] { "s5", "s5 state" }
    };
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to add a string array

```
List<string[]> synonyms = new List<string[]> 
    {
        new string[] { "enabled", "enable", "enabling" },
        new string[] { "disabled", "disable", "disabling" },
        new string[] { "s0", "s0 state" },
        new string[] { "s5", "s5 state" } 
    };
```

Answer (score 6):

Create implicitly typed arrays for your `List` initializer:

```
List<string[]> synonyms = new List<string[]> 
{
    new [] { "enabled", "enable", "enabling" },
    new [] { "disabled", "disable", "disabling" },
    new [] { "s0", "s0 state" },
    new [] { "s5", "s5 state" }
};
```

`new [] { ... }` is equivalent to doing `new string[] { ... }` when the types of the objects in the array are all `string`. You will get an error using the implicit syntax if the types of the objects in the array are different.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify that the inner objects are arrays so that it doesn't look for multi-parameter Add methods.

```
    List<string[]> synonyms = new List<string[]> 
    {
        new[] { "enabled", "enable", "enabling" },
        new[] { "disabled", "disable", "disabling" },
        new[] { "s0", "s0 state" },
        new[] { "s5", "s5 state" }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be that you're not making any instances of the arrays.

```
     List<string[]> synonyms = new List<string[]>
    {
       {new string[] { "enabled", "enable", "enabling" }},
       {new string[] { "disabled", "disable", "disabling" }},
       {new string[] { "s0", "s0 state" }},
       {new string[] { "s5", "s5 state" }}
    };
```